# How can I determine which folder the user was browsing when my program was invoked from the "sent to" menu?

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-explorer

I put a shortcut to my application in SendTo. Now I can select some files in Explorer and send them to my application. But how can I get the path where the files are? My program is supposed to create a new file in the parent directory that's common to all the received file names.

For example, if I have these files:

```
C:\one.txt
C:\1\
```

I select the file *one.txt* and the directory *1* in Explorer. How can I find out that the starting directory for these files is *C:\*?

I know I can use `ParamStr()` to get files' paths, but what then?
I could try to get common directory for all the files passed to my application, but if I select in *C:\* directories *1* and *2* and these directories look like this:

```
C:\1\4\5\one.txt
C:\1\4\two.txt
```

Then the starting directory is *C:\1\4*.

Comment: So you are asking how to extract the drive letter of filename portions? Why not just use [`ExtractFileDrive`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFileDrive)?

Comment: The starting path for your application is the 'start in' directory of your shortcut. Is it what you ask? In what way having more than one files is significant?

Comment: @Chris : No, my starting path can be C:\1 and not C:\ I want to know the base directory where are the files selected to be sent to my program.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz : This is not "Start in" field of shortcut. It is the directory the SendTo command was invoked from.

Comment: @Tom - Either your 'start in' field is empty or invalid, or we're not talking about the same thing.

Comment: The term *starting directory* can mean either the initial value of the *current working directory* when your program starts, or the "start in" directory configured in your program's shortcut file. If the OS honors the latter setting, then you should find that the former matches it. However, you seem to be asking instead for the directory the user was looking at in Explorer when he or she selected the files and invoked the "send to" command for your program. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Windows 7, all files selected in Explorer always reside in the same directory, so it's easy to know which directory the user was browsing. It's the same as the directory of any one file. Use [`ExtractFilePath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ExtractFilePath) for that.

As of Windows 7, though, Explorer lets you [put directories into groups called *libraries*](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Arrange-sort-or-group-your-files). All the files from all the folders are displayed together in a single view. Users can select files from multiple directories and send them all to your program at once. The view doesn't represent any real directory on the disk, so the question asked here is meaningless.

As an alternative, you could decide use [the ancestor directory common to all the files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773574.aspx) sent to your program, but that won't tell you much. For one thing, if the files reside on multiple drives, the common directory will be the *empty string*. The directory you calculate also might not be writable by the current account, even if the directories of one or more of the selected files are.

It will probably be easier to just use the directory of the *first* file you receive, or even to display a UI that asks the user what directory to use in the cases you can't determine it automatically. (Maybe you could pre-populate the result with the first directory, so the user doesn't have to do anything but approve your suggestion in the common case.)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about these "libraries" on Windows 7. On pre Win 7 ancestor directory should do what I want and I can't see a way how it can be empty. With Win7 I'll deal later, perhaps I'll just ask user what dir he wants to use, just like you suggested.

Comment: Actually, IDataObject (The Send To "file list") can contain files from different directories on all versions of Windows including Win95. How? From a single place; the file search!

Answer (score 0):

I think I will just take all the filenames passed to my program via ParamStr and use this function:
http://delphi.about.com/od/delphichallengesexercises/qt/delphi-extract-base-path-challenge.htm
to find common base path which should be the path where the SendTo was invoked.

Comment: I'm concerned that you seem to think the common parent directory has any kind of meaning in this context. It doesn't. The common parent directory might even be an empty string, so I'm not sure what you plan to do with it in general.

Comment: I want to do something with the selected files and create a new file in the directory where user selected these files. So it has meaning for me. I don't see how this can ever be an empty string.

Comment: You don't see how it can be an empty string? What do you think is the common folder of C:\foo.txt and D:\bar.txt?

Comment: When I said that the common ancestor folder didn't have meaning, I meant with regard to the current Windows Explorer view or your program's current directory. You're welcome to assign whatever meaning you want, but that doesn't guarantee it will make sense.

Comment: @RobKennedy : I don't need current Windows Explorer folder or my program's folder just the folder where user invoked SendTo event. And it seems common ancestor folder can do this. I don't think it is possible to select C:\foo.txt and D:\bar.txt and send them both to SendTo shortcut in one go. You can do this as 2 actions but then I will have my application stared twice and each instance can calculate nonempty ancestor folder.